# vainfo - va_getDriverName() returns -1

Tags: gstreamer, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to receive a video stream on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Gstreamer. 
I have installed most of the libraries related to Gstreamer-1.0. I understand that I have a problem with vainfo since that by itself returns the error too.
I'm getting this error:

```
pi@gunpi:~/gunshow/New $ gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'fps-display-video_sink-actual-sink-glimage': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayEGL\)\ gldisplayegl0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:12.802582180
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I don't really know what is causing the problem, maybe I haven't set the display up correctly?

When running the project, which the video stream will eventually get implemented into, I am also getting this error:

```
Cant find EGLConfig, returning null config
Unable to find an X11 visual which matches EGL config 0
Could not initialize OpenGL for RasterGLSurface, reverting to RasterSurface.
```

It is probably not really related, but it would be nice to resolve that too. I have installed QtCreator with apt-get so maybe it is not configured correctly. Can I fix this without having to build Qt myself? Because I was not able to configure it correctly for the RPi 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running in a desktop environment or just from plain command prompts?  You may also want to try looking into the GStreamer OMX elements for hardware decoding.

Comment: Im am running the commands from the desktop environment, and the same happens from plain command line. I have managed to get the udpsrc shown in a QWidget now, so I clearly don't need the driver any more. Still cant find EGLConfig, but its showing up, so I'm moving on for now. Hardware decoding is definitely on my list, do you have any good resources to get me going? Thanks